# Compiled QT program crashes when not debugging

Tags: c++, windows, qt, qt4

I'm debugging a weird issue where program only crashes when it is not ran with any debugging.
So if the program crashes and I debug it with Visual Studio it works fine. Also if I run it from QT Creator it works fine as long as I don't do release build without debugging.

The exit code is 1073807370 which produces no meaningful results through google.

QT version is 4.8.7 and I'm using MinGW. All libraries have been compiled with this setup on Windows 10.

Comment: It sounds like an uninitialized values problem. But without the actual minimal code, it's hard to say for sure.

Comment: is your project using different configurations for debug or release mode?

Comment: There is no meaningful difference between release and debug configurations. But since I can launch the release compiled build in visual studio debugging (without recompiling) just fine, I doubt it has any meaningful impact on the end result.

Comment: The exception code translates to `DBG_PRINTEXCEPTION_WIDE_C`. It is intended for communication with a debugger, and raised by `OutputDebugStringA` when a debugger is attached. It appears that some library in your code raises it without checking for a debugger. Look for code that calls `RaiseException` (or imports it).

Comment: Thanks that helped to explain it. Seems like there was a lib seh library in use and for some reason that caused the issues. I guess they need to be disabled when not debugging